# Get total_days value in a parameter from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table in which I have a column name as `total_days`, this column contains *the number of days the employee has taken leave*

What I want is, I want to take the above column in a parameter say `@NoOfDaysForDelayApproval`.

What I tried is

I get the desired output as below

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Please suggest what to do ?

**UPDATE**

Sorry not able to format it

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, andthe values of the parameters.

Comment: Can you provide some data with expected output ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff,..: Updated the question

Comment: can you provide the base table structure? i.e. XXACL_EMP_DELAY_APPROVAL_V  table structure

Comment: @AnujTripathi: added the structure, but couldn't format it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare your variable as `decimal` instead of `int`

```
declare @NoOfDaysForDelayApproval decimal(9,2)
```

It looks like that the datatype for your `Total_Days` column is decimal so you can create a similar datatype variable to store the value of sum in it.

See the demo in the image:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer Rahul sir, how to check that whether this _@NoOfDaysForDelayApproval_ has the data ?

Comment: @coder:- You can execute the same query which you are showing in your question and see the result.

Comment: I am executing the query with giving hardcode values to check whether the data exist or not, but it is just giving me message as `Command(s) completed successfully.` I tried like this

`declare @NoOfDaysForDelayApproval decimal(9,2)
      BEGIN
       select @NoOfDaysForDelayApproval = sum(Total_Days) 
        from XXACL_EMP_DELAY_APPROVAL_V    
        where cardno=2258
        and DMonth= 4
        and DYear = 2015
        END`

Comment: @coder:- I have created a sample table and executed the query and got the result. Please check.

Comment: Rahul sir: when I adding hardcode value for year and month it is working fine..but when add dynamic values as `@Month, @Year` it doesn't works ..

Comment: @coder:- First, please don't call me Sir. Second, then you need to provide the details as to how you are getting the value of `@Month` and `@Year`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98821/discussion-between-coder-and-rahul-tripathi).

Comment: `@Month` and `@Year` are the parameters which I will be giving while running the `SP`

Comment: hi Rahul, are you their ?

Comment: @coder:- Can you create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) for your question and demonstrate what you are trying to solve?

Comment: @coder:- To make your job easier, please do the edit in this fiddle. I have created it for you. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6123b/4

Comment: please find the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf931 : if condition is `M` I want that @NoofDelaysApproval to get printed on the basis of dynamic `Year` and `Month`. Do let me know if you need anything

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't allow you to keep SUM without GROUP BY clause on the first place. Also, you can not hold the value of variable type like that for the desired output. As I am not able to understand your complete question so I am posting below query; check it and let me know if this is what you are looking for or you want any change

```
    DECLARE @XXACL_EMP_DELAY_APPROVAL_V  TABLE 
(Emp_name varchar(10), total_days decimal(18,2), Year INT, MONTH INT)

INSERT INTO @XXACL_EMP_DELAY_APPROVAL_V VALUES
('A',2.00,2015,4),('B',1.00,2015,4),('C',4.00,2015,4),('D',6.00,2015,4), ('A',6.00,2015,4)

DECLARE @NoOfDays INT 

DECLARE @YearValue INT = 2015, @MonthValue INT = 4, @EmpName VARCHAR(10) = 'A'

SELECT  @NoOfDays = SUM(Total_days)
                    FROM @XXACL_EMP_DELAY_APPROVAL_V 
                    WHERE Year = @YearValue AND MONTH = @MonthValue AND Emp_name = @EmpName

SELECT @NoOfDays

SELECT DISTINCT A.Emp_name, A.Sum_of_total_days
FROM @XXACL_EMP_DELAY_APPROVAL_V V1 JOIN (
SELECT V2.Emp_name, SUM(V2.Total_days) AS 'Sum_of_total_days'
                    FROM @XXACL_EMP_DELAY_APPROVAL_V V2
                    WHERE V2.Year = @YearValue AND v2.MONTH = @MonthValue AND v2.Emp_name = @EmpName
                    GROUP BY V2.Emp_name ) A ON V1.Emp_name = A.Emp_Name
```

Comment: for me hardcode values are working fine as per the above  answer, Now my only issue is **When I m passing dynamic Month, Year it is not working**

Comment: @Coder I have updated my answer with variable values.

Comment: hi anuj, i really dont understand why are you giving me the whole code..I m just confused why my Year, and month are not passing when i am adding it dynamically.. the above code also doesn't works for me

Comment: @Coder The reason why I post this code to help you and myself understanding your real problem. However, like I mentioned in my answer, you can not aggregate like that in SQL. On the other hand, your view is already doing an aggregation on days so your first query is mathematically incorrect (you are trying to do aggregation on aggregation). Your second query make sense to me, please define variable and try to parameter it. It should work with no issues.